# SQL query get count item for report per day of the month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need sql query for report from table item per day(fix day1-day31 as column) of the month when i input **month and year**.

This is my table (item)
  ID   |   NAME  |   DATE
---------------------------------------------------
   1   |   ITEM A |   2015-2-25 13:37:49
   2   |   ITEM A |   2015-2-25 14:37:49
   3   |   ITEM A |   2015-2-26 13:30:55
   4   |   ITEM B |   2015-2-26 15:37:49
   5   |   ITEM B |   2015-2-26 17:57:49
   6   |   ITEM C |   2015-2-27 13:00:33

---

(input month=02 and year=2015)
What I need to achieve with a view is the following:

NAME  | 1| 2| 3|…|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|Total
------------------------------------------------------
ITEM A| 0| 0| 0|…| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 
ITEM B| 0| 0| 0|…| 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 
ITEM C| 0| 0| 0|…| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1

---

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry this is my first post.

Comment: It is pivoting so best approach is do it in code side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a PIVOT in your query

```
SELECT name, 
       [1], 
       [2], 
       [3], 
       [4], 
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9],
       [10],
       [11],
       [12],
       [13],
       [14],
       [15],
       [16],
       [17],
       [18],
       [19], 
       [20], 
       [21], 
       [22], 
       [23], 
       [24], 
       [25], 
       [26], 
       [27], 
       [28], 
       [29], 
       [30], 
       [31],
       ([1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] + [13] + [14] + [15] + [16] + [17] + [18] + [19] +  [20] + [21] + [22] + [23] + [24] + [25] + [26] + [27] + [28] + [29] + [30] + [31]) as total
FROM   
(
    SELECT Name, 
        id, 
        Datepart(day, [date]) day 
    FROM   item 
    WHERE  MONTH([date]) = 2 AND YEAR([date]) = 2015
) x 
PIVOT 
(
    count(id) 
    FOR day IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19],  [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]) 
) p
```

Comment: I can use this query for solved my problem.  it work.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi sir, i have new issue ,  my table have new col [Amount] and i need sum this col [Amount] replace count(id) please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you. First test data:

```
CREATE TABLE data ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(30), [Date] datetime)

INSERT INTO data ([ID], [Name], [Date])
SELECT 1,'ITEM A','2015-2-25 13:37:49'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'ITEM A','2015-2-25 14:37:49'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'ITEM A','2015-2-26 13:30:55'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'ITEM B','2015-2-26 15:37:49'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'ITEM B','2015-2-26 17:57:49'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'ITEM C','2015-2-27 13:00:33'
```

Then the query. Note you can use any data range, so if you want a full month just calculate that and put it in the @startDate and @endDate

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME='25-Feb-2015'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME='28-Feb-2015'
DECLARE @numberOfDays INT = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)

declare @dayColumns TABLE (delta int, colName varchar(12))

-- Produce 1 row for each day in the report. Note that this is limited by the 
-- number of objects in sysobjects (which is about 2000 so its a high limit)
-- Each row contains a delta date offset, @startDate+delta gives each date to report 
-- which is converted to a valid SQL column name in the format colYYYYMMDD
INSERT INTO @dayColumns (delta, colName)
SELECT delta, 'col'+CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(day,delta,@startDate),112) as colName from (
  select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sysobjects.id))-1 as delta FROM sysobjects 
) daysAhead
WHERE delta<=@numberOfDays

-- Create a comma seperated list of columns to report
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
SELECT @cols=CASE WHEN @cols='' THEN @cols ELSE @cols+',' END + colName FROM @dayColumns ORDER BY delta
DECLARE @totalCount AS NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
SELECT @totalCount=CASE WHEN @totalCount='' THEN '' ELSE @totalCount+' + ' END + 'ISNULL(' + colName +',0)' FROM @dayColumns ORDER BY delta

-- Produce a SQL statement which outputs a variable number of pivoted columns
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @query=
'declare @days TABLE (reportDay date, colName varchar(12))

INSERT INTO @days (reportDay, colName)
SELECT DATEADD(day,Delta,'''+CONVERT(varchar(22),@startDate,121)+'''), ''col''+CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(day,delta,'''+CONVERT(varchar(22),@startDate,121)+'''),112) as colName from (
  select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sysobjects.id))-1 as Delta FROM sysobjects 
) daysAhead
WHERE Delta<='+CAST(@numberOfDays as varchar(10))+'

SELECT pivoted.*,'+@totalCount+' as total FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    select data.Name, d.colName, 1 as numRows
    from @days d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data ON CAST(data.[Date] as DATE)=d.reportDay
  ) as s
  PIVOT (
    SUM(numRows) FOR colName in ('+@cols+')
  ) as pa
) as pivoted
WHERE Name is not null'

-- Run the query
EXEC (@query)
```

Output is:

```
    Name                           col20150225 col20150226 col20150227 col20150228 total
    ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
    ITEM A                         2           1           NULL        NULL        3
    ITEM B                         NULL        2           NULL        NULL        2
    ITEM C                         NULL        NULL        1           NULL        1
```

You can determine the date of each column by parsing the column header in your presentation code (it's format is colYYYYMMDD).

Comment: Thank you very much, This your query and concept is very work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar,PaymentDate,103) AS date,
       DatePart(MONTH,PaymentDate) as month,
       CAST(SUM(Total_Amount) as INT) as Revenue 
from Tbl_Name 
where YEAR(PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND MONTH(PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
GROUP BY convert(varchar,PaymentDate,103),
         DatePart(MONTH,PaymentDate) 
order by date;
```